# failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, npm

I'm really new to Docker and would like to create a container that has all my angular website and its dependencies in it. I read some data and how-to's to do it but I keep struggling.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules && rm ./package-lock.json
# RUN npm install -g npm@8.5.2
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/demo2 /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks fine. What's causing the issue is probably a dependency in your package.json or package-lock.json files. Can you add those to your post?